# SQL Envia valor NULL para uma coluna DateTime

Tags: sql-server, winforms, vb.net

Tenho um form em VB.NET onde o usuário informa as datas de entrega e previsão de entrega do pedido e outras informações. Sendo que ele ainda não tem, por exemplo, a data de entrega por ainda não ter sido informado pela transportadora.

Minha query pega todas as informações do form guarda num ArrayList e envia para o método que envia para o banco. Coloquei um checkBox no campo 'Data de Entrega' para enviar a data caso este esteja marcado. Mas quero enviar NULL se não estiver marcado, mas está dando erro, dizendo que o parâmetro não tem valor.

Fiz destas formas dentro do ArrayList antes de enviar para o método:

```
Dados.Add("NULL")
Dados.Add("'NULL'")
Dados.Add(Nothing)
```

'Dados' é o nome do ArrayList que o método recebe e substitui nos parâmetros.
A parte onde está o valor da data de entrega é esse:

```
DT_ENTREGA = @DT_ENTREGA
```

Fiz uma solução provisória até saber como fazer.
Estou enviando o valor `1900-01-01` onde deveria ser NULL, quando termina de executar a query, envio um update para atualizar o valor para NULL onde aquela coluna conter `1900-01-01`. Funcionou, mas acho que o procedimento não é esse.

O método recebe um ArrayList com vários valores e depois jogo nos parâmetros:

```
objcmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@DT_ENTREGA", Registro(5)))
```

O update fiz assim:

```
UPDATE LOGISTICA SET DT_ENTREGA = NULL WHERE DT_ENTREGA = '1900-01-01' AND PEDIDO = @PEDIDO;
```

Comment: Não entendi nada do que está acontecendo e qual é o problema, talvez falta mais código para dar para entender. A única coisa que ficou claro para mim é que está usando `ArrayList` o que não é recomendado.

Comment: Meu problema é que não consigo enviar NULL para o campo DateTime do SQL quando o campo no form não estiver preenchido.

Comment: Tudo bem, mas qual é o problema, envie um `null`. Se não consegue, explique o que está fazendo, porque não consegue, o que ocorre.

Comment: É verdade, desculpe. Editei o texto e acrescentei a parte onde adiciono o NULL no ArrayList do método.

Comment: Os dois primeiros não fazem sentido. O terceiro em tese é pra funcionar, mas não sei porque nunca usei o `ArrayList` ele é problemático. O problema pode até ser outro porque ainda não está claro qual é o problema, o fluxo do código, as coisas estão muito soltas. O que é este `Registro(5)`. A gente tem que ficar adivinhando o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Particularmente não tenho problemas com o ArrayList, acho muito útil para passar muitos parâmetros. Fiz outro teste usando Dados.Add("") e ele gravou '1900-01-01'. Queria mesmo era passar alguma coisa no parâmetro para gravar NULL no banco. Registro(5) é a 6a posição do ArrayList 'Dados'

Comment: Voce não precisa passar "NULL", adicione o paramentro em branco. O sql que vai inserir NULL na tabela se ela aceitar campos nulos.

Comment: @LindomarLemos você tem problemas com ele, mas ainda não percebeu. Não vou conseguir ajudar mais do que isto.

Comment: @Robss70 não funcionou. O parâmetro em branco gravou '1900-01-01'.

Comment: @bigown que informação precisa? Acho que meu problema está nesta parte: SqlParameter("@DT_ENTREGA", " valor passado") onde 'valor passado' deve ser algo que o SqlParameter aceito como '= NULL'. Posso também estar errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua stored procedure "caso esteja usando uma" declare o parâmetro assim:

```
@DT_ENTREGA datetime = null
```

Desta forma quando você passar o parâmetro `Dados.Add("")` a tabela ficara com o valor null por padrão.

Outra forma seria passar o valor do parâmetro como `DBNull.Value;`

Ou então `SqlDateTime.Null;`

Acredito não serem as formas corretas de resolver, mais vai te dar mais tempo para pensar a respeito de como resolver isto.

Comment: muito obrigado, usei Dados.Add(DBNull.Value) e funcionou. O SqlParameter("@DT_ENTREGA", Registro(5)), converteu o valor do ArrayList para NULL e gravou no banco.

Comment: @LindomarLemos, por que você está usando `ArrayList` ? Usando ele podem acontecer erros em tempo de execução em alguns casos de conversão, enquanto o `List<T>` geraria o erro em tempo de compilação.

Comment: comecei a usar o ArrayList devido a uma video-aula onde estava aprendendo a passar valores para o método gravar no banco. Realmente ele dá erros em tempo de execução. Também uso lista porém para ler do banco. Por exemplo, esse query que montei é um INSERT  ou UPDATE personalizado do usuário. Se ele quer gravar a data, o parâmetro vai com a data, se ele não quiser, o parâmetro vai vazio, isso no formulário inteiro. Coloquei todos os campos num ArrayList e envio para o método, uso um validador para os campos antes de enviar. Lá no método informo qual a posição para cada coluna e gravo.

Comment: Mas posso pensar também numa lista, seria prático não precisar numerar como faço no ArrayList caso altere a posição. Não havia pensado nisso.